# How to add animations to a text using material ui

Tags: css, material-ui

I am trying to add an animation, where I want the added text to have a 3d effect and rotate 360 degrees at the same time using material ui

```
<Typography variant="overline"  color="secondary"  style={{fontFamily:'Roboto'}}>
  All about your needs
</Typography>
```

I want that effect to the above mentioned text , how should I approach this problem?

Comment: you mean `svg` in action?

Comment: ah do I need to use svg ? I am a bit new to material ui

Comment: Yeah, it makes your simple and clean.

Comment: how can I apply svg to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's jsut a css behaviour, look at the following:

```css
@keyframes rotatee {
  from{transform:rotateY(0deg)}

    to {transform:rotateY(360deg)}
  
}

.toto > span {
    animation: rotatee 3s linear infinite;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="toto">
  <span>TEXT</span>
</span>
```